# django-unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
sales=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=3,blank=True,null=True)
total_asset=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=3,blank=True,null=True)
asset_turnover=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=3,blank=True,null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DupontView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
        context["total_asset"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Avg('total_asset'))
        context["asset_turnover"] = (context['sales']['sales__sum']/context['total_asset']['total_asset__avg'])
```

I have tried the solution like :

```
from decimal import Decimal

context["asset_turnover"] = "%.2f" % (context['sales']['sales__sum']/decimal(context['total_asset']['total_asset__avg']))
```

It would report error like "global name 'decimal' is not defined"

please tell me how to solve this, thanks a lot~~~

Comment: You can't convert a dict to a Decimal; perhaps you need to get the value in the dict first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have imported:

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

but you are using:

```
... ['sales__sum']/decimal(contex...
```

**Python is case sensitive** so you have no **d**ecimal in scope.